# Is "worsening" an adjective in this ocntext?

Tags: parsing, headlinese

The headline in NY times is:

"Why Climate Change Makes It Harder to Fight Fire With Fire

Worsening wildfires have led officials to embrace planned fires to thin forests ahead of disaster. But the warming world is making it tougher to do safely."

is "Worsening" an adjective???

Comment: The verb ***to worsen*** is almost always used intransitively / "reflexively". So it's more likely to occur as *His condition worsened [after doing X]* rather than *Doing X worsened his condition.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *worsening* in this construction is an adjective. It takes the first definition in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/worsening)

> becoming worse:
> He had to give up all sport because of worsening back problems.